# Parallel Dense Matrix Diagonalization in C++

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp, linear-algebra, openblas

I have written a parallelized C++ code using OPENMP. I have been using EIGEN to deal with linear algebra. However, Eigen does not parallelize the eigen solver for dense matrix's. I' ve built OPENBLAS with openmp, however I do not see any performance boost when using more threads (using LAPACKE_zheevd function).

What do you suggest?

This is the code I have been using:

```cpp
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
// C-wrapper to the Fortran Lapack lib.
#include <lapacke.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
  const int N = 1024;
  
  printf("Matrix size=%i\n", N);
  printf("Number of threads=%i\n", omp_get_max_threads());
  
  int LDA=N, info,i,j;
  double w[N];
  
  lapack_complex_double * a;
  
  a = (lapack_complex_double *) malloc( N*LDA*sizeof(lapack_complex_double) );
  
  srand(999); /* Dense random matrix */
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    for(j = 0; j < N; j++ )
      a[i*LDA + j] = lapack_make_complex_double(rand() , rand());
  // LAPACKE_zheevd: computes all
  // eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a
  // complex Hermitian matrix A using divide
  // and conquer algorithm

  auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
  info = LAPACKE_zheevd( LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, 'V', 'L', N, a, LDA, w );
  auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast< std::chrono::milliseconds >( std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start);
  std::cout << duration.count() << std::endl;
  /* Check for convergence */
  
  if( info > 0 ) {
    printf( "The algorithm failed to compute eigenvalues.\n" );
    exit( 1 );
  }
  /* Print the extreme eigenvalues */
  printf("Smallest eigen value=%6.2f\n",w[0]);
  printf("Largest value=%6.2f\n\n",w[N-1]);
}
```

Comment: I think you need to investigate the algorithm that Eigen uses. It could be that the Blas routines operate on very tiny matrices, so parallelism will not help much.

Comment: Just double checking did you set the number of threads correctly?

Comment: @MadFred  Yes. I have. I can see as well that they are being used.

Answer (score 1):

`LAPACKE_zheevd` is a LAPACK primitive, not a BLAS one. The former provide advanced linear algebra functions (eg. linear solvers, singular value decomposition, etc.). The later provides very basic linear algebra functions like (dense) matrix multiplication, vector-matrix product, dot product, etc. LAPACK library use BLAS libraries internally to speed things up as much as possible (typically by rewriting algorithm so to use matrix multiplications that are highly optimized).

OpenBLAS mainly provide BLAS primitives, not really LAPACK ones. It implements only few LAPACK functions so to use their internal parallel matrix multiplications. The implementation of the provided LAPACK function can be far from being optimal regarding the target input (it is only fast when the matrix multiplication is large enough so to run in parallel). Most functions are coming from the NetLib implementation which is a standard Open-Source LAPACK package. Regarding Z Put it shortly, OpenBLAS is a quite good BLAS implementation but not a great LAPACK one (though it can provide a substantial improvement over the NetLib implementation).

The thing is parallelizing most LAPACK function actually very hard. There are several highly-skilled research & engineering teams working hard on the topic since decades so to write fast parallel LAPACK primitive. AFAIK, results are mixed and the scalability is rather disappointing for some primitives despite the effort so far. This is a difficult task especially because they need to care about the *numerical stability* of the algorithm and balance computation over many cores.

On top of that, there is another huge issue: memory-bound algorithms does not scale. Indeed, few cores are often able to saturate a major part of the memory bandwidth of a computing node. The thing is many (part of) LAPACK primitives are rather memory-bound. Not to mention this is likely not gonna be better in the future because of the *memory wall*.

---

Regarding specifically `LAPACKE_zheevd`, there is an [**open issue**](https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/issues/1560) of OpenBLAS showing the implementation of ZHEEV is actually pretty inefficient and using multiple threads tends to *decrease* performance. The **Intel MKL** implements this much more efficiently (though the scalability is still not great). It might be a good idea to try alternative library like **PLASMA** (specifically designed for multi-core architecture). Another solution is to implement this based on *state-of-the-art research papers* on the topic (typically by implementing a task-based tiled singular-value decomposition), but this is far from being easy.